# Updating a RecyclerView item when Activity closed

Tags: android, listeners

I have a RecyclerView and the user can cheer teams on the recyclerview layout or clicks on the items and cheer the teams  inside the match page, what i need to do is to update the recyclerview cheers bar in the first layout  when ever the user enters the full match page and cheer a team

[first recyclerview layout iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf9rc.png)

[Full Match Layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQ1m.jpg)

I need to create some kind of alistener that will be activited in

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("posss", "onBackPressed:cheeredTeam:"+cheeredTeam);
    Log.d("posss", "onBackPressed:pos:" + pos);
    // Activite Listener with (recycler position , cheered team ) 
}
```

Comment: The full match layout is above the recyclerview layout in the back stack?

Comment: No the recycler view is inside a fragment, and the full match is an activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `startActivityForResult(Intent, requestCode)` when starting your full match activity! Then, when the user returns to your RecyclerView, you would want to insert `setResult(Intent)` before that. Then, in your fragment create the `onActivityResult()` function, that will receive the updated information through the Intent.

Look at this too, when making your onActivityResult method: [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884)

Comment: No Problem, happy to help :)